# CURL: How retain cookies between requests?

Tags: linux, bash, curl

I need to login to a page and then submit an entry.
i'm able to login with the following code

```
curl $HOST -s -L -b $COOKIE -c $COOKIE -d "login=submit&login_name=$USER&login_password=$PASS" -o $OUTPUT
```

but when i try to submit an entry i'm not logged in anymore

```
curl $HOSTADDNEWS -L -b $COOKIE -c $COOKIE -A $HEADER -d "title=$TITLE" -o $OUTPUT.add.news
```

How to retain cookies between requests?

Comment: These commands _do_ retain the cookies (with -b and -c specifying the same file assuming curl has permission to write to it)  - and you could use --trace-ascii to get that shown nicely. Your problem is probably not exactly that...

Comment: Thanks! the problem was with $COOKIE variable it had a "slash"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to  Daniel Stenberg! $COOKIE variable had a "slash" in it... it still saved to file but wasn't able to use it.

Comment: You're welcome, although I didn't really answer the question... :-)